# Spring boot+tomcat performance: Server-sent events vs websocket vs old-school REST

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-boot, tomcat

Suppose, we have a Spring boot application built with Tomcat and web-client works in browser. And we need to indicate some info about processes, runned on server-side. Server side is Spring boot application built with Tomcat.
As we know, there is 3 ways to implement such functionality:
 1. websocket;
 2. server-sent-events;
 3. REST-service (GetMapping) on server side and timer on browser-side which polling that service with GET-requests each second.

Let's suppose that we have a lot clients, and that exactly our code have equal time and memory consumption in all 3 versions. Question: which way is cheapest by CPU, by memory and, maybe, by available connections?

Comment: CPU and memory are irrelevant considerations here compared to more fundamental questions like your clients' access patterns, what features your load balancers/gateways support, and the capabilities/functionality of your client libraries and developers.